# Close a newly opened tab or window in Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, windows-7, selenium, ide, selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE with Windows7 and Firefox, an automatic click on a link may produce either a new tab or a new window.

close() closes the original window or tab, not the new one.  Maybe if I had the ID of the newly created one I could select it and then close it but I don't know how to do this automatically.  I've asked on the Selenium forum and read the questions here, but they focus on WebDriver, not the IDE.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
 Stig
```

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem and found a solution:

1. click on link that opens the new tab
2. add command `waitForPopUp`
3. set focus to new tab via command `selectPopUp`
4. make your verifications or other commands regarding to your content in new tab
5. use command `close` to close tab
6. use command `selectWindow` to set focus to the old window

Screenshot of my Selenium IDE commands:

[image: Selenium IDE switch tabs]

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectWindow(windowID)` command to switch to new window in Se IDE. You can select new window by its windowID/name/title.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you Surya, but I don't know how to get the Window ID, etc. of a window that was opened by the script by clicking a link.  There are too many to get each window ID by hand so the IDE commands have to find that information, somehow, from the link info.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Agreed with surya use selectWindow(windowID), you can get the window title by right click on the page check the option verifyTitle and in front of that you have your Title. Hope it helps out.

Answer (score -1):

selectWindow(windowID) has option to mention title of the webpage/window as a way to identify the target window.

syntax = selectWindow  title=My Special Window

note: title = title of webpage that is visisble in webpage's title bar. Or right click on webpage and select menu "Page source". In source doc, select the text between ....

So if the title of webpage = My Special Window, you will see My Special Window.

Hope this will help.

Swasati Paul

Comment: Welcome to SO! You don't ever need to put the "Hope this will help and name" part of the answer. You may want to use some of the formatting features to make your answer more organized and easier to digest. Specifically with regards to code and steps (e.g. bullets or numbers).

Answer (score -1):

You could use the iterator to iterate amongst the windows, close the new window and come back to the originalWindow. And you can put this under the `try` block because it will only iterate if a new window opens. Or else, it will continue executing normally in the current window.

```
try{     
Set <Strings> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator <String> it = ids.iterator();
String currentPage = it.next();
String newPage = it.next();
driver.switchTo().window(newPage);
driver.close(); //it will close the new window and automatically come back to the currentPage
}
finally
{
//continue with your script here
//this script will run regardless of the execution of the execution of the try block
}
```