# how do I close tabs in Selenium ide?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I don't find Any example in 
Chrome> selenium IDE example
I even tried the "Select window"
by

1. tab
2. Name
3. CloseAllOter

Comment: possibly duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973908/close-a-newly-opened-tab-or-window-in-selenium-ide

Comment: but still no answer

Comment: are you using the latest selenium ide on Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to close a tab in WebDriver or Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502255/is-there-a-way-to-close-a-tab-in-webdriver-or-protractor)

Comment: @Naveen
yes last version

Comment: Can you try the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18252581/7964299

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the tab that you want to close and [close it](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#close).
Here is my example :

```
store window handle | root |    
click | xpath_to_link_element |
```

after executing of these commands root tab is saved and new tab opens. New window settings were set like this: [image]

```
select window | handle=${userAgreement} |
```

This command make browser switch to a new tab.

```
close | userAgreement |
select window | handle=${root} |
```

Close new tab and switch back.